# hibernate subquery not work

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have to porting sql queries from mysql workbench to Hibernate, but for this query :

```
Query query5_1 = em.createQuery("select result.id,result.name,result.surname,max(result.sales) 
from (select m.warehousemen.id as id,m.warehousemen.name as name,m.warehousemen.surname as 
surname,sum(m.size) as sales from MovementsEntity m group by m.warehousemen.id) result");
```

i get this error:

[error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp5aI.png)

please help me, thanks anyway

Comment: It's always recommended to post your error message here, since the links could be broken in the future. Aren't you missing an 'as' before 'result'?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do such things with HQL, you should use native query for this.